# C++ signed integer conversion to unsigned with more bits

Tags: c++, integer, type-conversion

I wonder about type conversion from a smaller signed integer to a larger unsigned integer.  It appears that the compiler first converts the signed integer to a signed integer of the same size as the destination, then to the unsigned integer.

Regard the following C++ code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef int sint;
typedef unsigned __int64 luint;

int main(int, char**) {
   assert(sizeof(luint) > sizeof(sint));
   sint i = -10;
   luint j = i;
   std::cout << std::hex << j;
}
```

Under Visual C++ this yields: `fffffffffffffff6`.

This is as I like it.  Can I be sure that all compilers will behave this way?  If the signed integer would be converted to an unsigned first and then to the new size, the result would have been `fffffff6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signed to unsigned conversion uses *modulo 2<sup>n</sup>* arithmetic. From the C++11 Standard, section **4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]** (§4.7/2):

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

So `j` takes the value 2<sup>*64*</sup> − 10, which is `0xfffffffffffffff6`.

Comment: That part of the standard needed some re-reading, but now it makes sense to me! Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry, I could have added that the answer to "Can I be sure that all compilers will behave this way?" is "Yes, it is guaranteed by the Standard" =)